# Flutter: Should I use BloC class per page(UI/View)?

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I am studying and developing a flutter app as an Android developer.

I am not familiar with flutter, dart, and the BloC architecture pattern.
Anyway, I am applying BloC patter into my flutter app.

Because I learned the Clean Architecture, I wanted to apply clean architecture too.
The first time, I separated the BloC class as per the feature.

My toy app is Todo app.

So I have a very simple features and I defined the BloC like:

- Create a todo > CreateTodoBloc
- Update a todo > UpdateTodoBloc
- Get todos > GetTodosBloc
- Delete a todo > DeleteTodoBloc

In my home UI/View, todo list is displayed and it can be updated when the user completes the todo.

In this case, the home UI/View should have two BloC: GetTodosBloc and UpdateTodoBloc

This can show the todo list, and when the user clicks the button of the todo, the todo is updated and saved into the local database.

But the problem is that the todo list is not changed!
My home ui/view is showing the todo list differently per todo's complete status.

It looks like that my concept is wrong...
To resolve this, I think I should use BloC per the UI/View.

Then the Home UI/View will have only one bloc object: "HomeBloc".

And the "HomeBloc" may show the ui and update the todo.

So...

I want to hear other developer's opinion and know is there another best practice.

Comment: Bloc is old school Flutter. Everyone is using package provider these days.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you're still working on Flutter projects after that long time.

I really like your way of thinking and implementing clean architecture in Flutter.

I have been using Uncle Bob's clean architecture principles lately and it's astonishing, one of the five principles he has the `Single Responsibility Principle` and I honestly think of BLoC as a way to manage your state ONLY the same thing I thought about ViewModel if you know about it in Google's AAC (Android Architecture Components) so they actually should not be performing any logical operations inside it.

It should only get commands from the UI and pass it to the use cases which should make the logic then return the result once again to the view.

I just made a test app that implements The Clean Architecture principles and would like to get your feedback on it, you can access the repo from [here](https://github.com/TahaMalas/Flutter-Clean-Architecture).

Comment: That's definitely true it's a lot of code and takes lots of time specially if you make unit tests as in the repo, but also I believe that's awesome for a huge apps and scalable ones, because this architecture provides you with the extensibility of your app.

Comment: I truly encourage you to see this video by Robert Martin to see its benefits 

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dKZ-dWaCiU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2dKZ-dWaCiU)

Comment: "it's a lot of code...I believe that's awesome for huge apps" Well if huge apps is you're goal, it certainly seems like a verbose programming style will help you achieve that goal sooner!! 

Comment: 18:42 into Martin's talk and finally "Let's talk about architecture." If this guy's verbose presentation style is any indication of his coding style then yes he must be writing "huge apps".

Comment: You're just quoting unrelated parts of the comment and using them to not even make a point, I'm more than happy to discuss with you the pros and cons of this approach.

First of all, Separation of concerns, each class has one and one purpose only, that'd make navigation inside your project's files much more easier, so for that as I said in the original answer, in my point of view BLoC is only responsible for state management and that's exactly what I'm using it for.

Comment: Secondly, as you saw in the repo, if you've dived deep into it, the core of the app is the domain layer (Use cases / Interactors), which are totally separated from the framework we're working with, so if we decide someday to migrate to Angular dart, the domain layer would remain the same the changes will be made in the presentation layer (The UI part of the app) and the data layer (From where we're getting our data).

Comment: Lastly, the data layer, if we ever decided to change the way we're making API requests from Dio to http or any other library, the only thing will be changed is the implementation of the remote data sources, because the contract through which we set the ground roles of the data we want to be getting in and out from the app.

Finally I'm not convincing anyone to follow this approach I'm telling you my experience and lots of big companies are following and demanding people working this way.

I'm always available for any question or discussion

Comment: Yep I isolate the model, local storage routines, and remote storage routines too! How to balancing architecture bulk with readable, brief, direct code is a judgement call. No two people ever quite judge it the same.